# How do you perform a recursive query in cypher where there is a conditional within the path relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to setup a new graph database to contain records of products and their relationship on each other's versioned components. For each product it can have many components, and each component is made up of multiple versions. Each version can be dependent on none or many versions of any other components. I want to be able to query this database to pick any version of a component and determine what other versioned components it is depended on, or what depends on it.

The data structure I have attempted in my examples is not defined yet, so if a completely different structure is more suitable I'm open to changing it. I originally considered setting the `DEPENDS_ON` relationship directly between members. However, as new members will be added over time if a new member is added and falls within the version_min and version_max range of an existing records dependancy range, I would then need to go back and identify all affected records and update all of them, which doesn't feel like it would scale over time. This is what lead to the idea of having a member being dependent on a component, with the version limits defined in the relationship parameters.

I have put together a very simple example of 3 products (sample data at the end), with a single type of component and 1 version of each in all cases except one. I've then added only two dependencies into this example, 'a' depends on a range of 'b' versions, and one of the 'b' versions depends on a version of 'c'.

I would like to be able to perform a query to say "give me all downstream members which member `prod_a_comp_1_v_1` depends on". Similarly I would like to do this in reverse too, which I imagine is achieved by just reversing some of the relationship parameters.

So far I've achieved this for a single hop (list b versions which a depends on), shown here:

```
MATCH
p=(a:member{name:'prod_a_comp_1_v_1'})-[d:DEPENDS_ON]->(c:component)<-[v:VERSION_OF]-(b:member) WHERE b.version >= d.version_min AND b.version <= d.version_max
RETURN p
```

[image: Single hop filtered dependent member versions]

But I don't know how to get it to recursively perform this query on the results of this first match. I investigated variable length/depths, but because there is a conditional parameter in the relationship in the variable depth (DEPENDS_ON), I could not get this to work.

From the example data if querying all downstream dependencies of `prod_a_comp_1_v_1` it should return: [`prod_b_comp_1_v_2`, `prod_b_comp_1_v_3`, `prod_c_comp_1_v_1`].
e.g. this figure:
[image: Recursive query of all downstream dependencies]

Currently my thought is to use the above query and perform the repeated call on the database based on the results from the client end (capturing circular loops etc.), but that seems very undesirable.

Sample data:

```
CREATE
(prod_a:product {name:'prod_a'}),
(prod_a_comp_1:component {name: 'prod_a_comp_1', type:'comp_1'}),
(prod_a_comp_1)-[:COMPONENT_OF {type:'comp_1'}]->(prod_a),
(prod_a_comp_1_v_1:member {name:'prod_a_comp_1_v_1', type:'comp_1', version:1}),
(prod_a_comp_1_v_1)-[:VERSION_OF {version:1}]->(prod_a_comp_1)

CREATE
(prod_b:product {name:'prod_b'}),
(prod_b_comp_1:component {name: 'prod_b_comp_1', type:'comp_1'}),
(prod_b_comp_1)-[:COMPONENT_OF {type:'comp_1'}]->(prod_b),
(prod_b_comp_1_v_1:member {name:'prod_b_comp_1_v_1', type:'comp_1', version:1}),
(prod_b_comp_1_v_2:member {name:'prod_b_comp_1_v_2', type:'comp_1', version:2}),
(prod_b_comp_1_v_3:member {name:'prod_b_comp_1_v_3', type:'comp_1', version:3}),
(prod_b_comp_1_v_1)-[:VERSION_OF {version:1}]->(prod_b_comp_1),
(prod_b_comp_1_v_2)-[:VERSION_OF {version:2}]->(prod_b_comp_1),
(prod_b_comp_1_v_3)-[:VERSION_OF {version:3}]->(prod_b_comp_1)

CREATE
(prod_c:product {name:'prod_c'}),
(prod_c_comp_1:component {name: 'prod_c_comp_1', type:'comp_1'}),
(prod_c_comp_1)-[:COMPONENT_OF {type:'comp_1'}]->(prod_c),
(prod_c_comp_1_v_1:member {name:'prod_c_comp_1_v_1', type:'comp_1', version:1}),
(prod_c_comp_1_v_1)-[:VERSION_OF {version:1}]->(prod_c_comp_1)

CREATE
(prod_a_comp_1_v_1)-[:DEPENDS_ON {version_min:2, version_max:3}]->(prod_b_comp_1),
(prod_b_comp_1_v_3)-[:DEPENDS_ON {version_min:1, version_max:100}]->(prod_c_comp_1)
```

Figure showing full sample data set:
[image: Full example dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First, let me first adjust your node labels to use camel casing to follow the suggested neo4j naming convention. I will also rename `member` to the much more intuitive `Version` label.*

You can change your data model so that the `DEPENDS_ON` relationship type directly connects `Version` nodes. Although this can result in many more relationships, it will also allow you to skip version numbers within a min/max range (e.g., if some version numbers in the range are unreliable/expensive/the wrong color/etc.). But the main reason to do that is it will make your use case extremely simple.

Here is how to create an updated version of your sample data, with my suggested adjustments (and with less redundant info):

```
CREATE
  (a:Product {id: 'a'}),
  (a_1:Component {id: 'a_1', type: 'comp_1'})-[:COMPONENT_OF]->(a),
  (a_1_1:Version {id: 'a_1_1', version: 1})-[:VERSION_OF]->(a_1)

CREATE
  (b:Product {id: 'b'}),
  (b_1:Component {id: 'b_1', type: 'comp_1'})-[:COMPONENT_OF]->(b),
  (b_1_1:Version {id: 'b_1_1', version:1})-[:VERSION_OF]->(b_1),
  (b_1_2:Version {id: 'b_1_2', version:2})-[:VERSION_OF]->(b_1),
  (b_1_3:Version {id: 'b_1_3', version:3})-[:VERSION_OF]->(b_1)

CREATE
  (c:Product {id:'c'}),
  (c_1:Component {id: 'c_1', type: 'comp_1'})-[:COMPONENT_OF]->(c),
  (c_1_1:Version {id: 'c_1_1', version: 1})-[:VERSION_OF]->(c_1)

CREATE
  (a_1_1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(b_1_2),
  (a_1_1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(b_1_3),
  (b_1_3)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(c_1_1)
```

Here is how to get the versions that version `a_1_1` depends on:

```
MATCH (v:Version)-[:DEPENDS_ON*]->(x:Version)
WHERE v.id = 'a_1_1'
RETURN x.id
```

And here is the result:

```
╒═══════╕
│"x.id" │
╞═══════╡
│"b_1_3"│
├───────┤
│"c_1_1"│
├───────┤
│"b_1_2"│
└───────┘
```

[UPDATE]

To reduce the total number of `DEPENDS_ON` relationships, we can use optional `VersionSet` nodes that represent shared collections of versions. A `VersionSet` can be used as either endpoint of a `DEPENDS_ON` relationship, just like `Version` nodes. And they can even be chained together.

We can modify the above Cypher example code by replacing its last `CREATE` clause with the following. In this new example, VersionSet `s1` represents dependencies shared by versions `a_1_1` and `d_1_1`. Notice how sets `s2` and `s1` are part of a chain. Also notice how version `d_1_1` depends on a `Version` as well as `VersionSet`. There is a lot of flexibility, and we can even handle a chain of version sets with overlapping versions (`d_1_1` depends on `c_1_1` in 2 different ways).

```
...

CREATE
  (d:Product {id:'d'}),
  (d_1:Component {id: 'd_1', type: 'comp_2'})-[:COMPONENT_OF]->(d),
  (d_1_1:Version {id: 'd_1_1', version: 1})-[:VERSION_OF]->(d_1)

CREATE
  (s1:VersionSet),
  (s1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(b_1_2),
  (s1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(b_1_3),
  (s2:VersionSet),
  (s2)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(s1),      // chaining 2 sets
  (s2)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(b_1_1)

CREATE
  (a_1_1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(s1),
  (b_1_3)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(c_1_1),
  (d_1_1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(s2),
  (d_1_1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(c_1_1) // redundant dependency
```

The resulting graph: [image]

This updated query returns the *distinct* version dependencies for `d_1_1`:

```
MATCH (v:Version)-[:DEPENDS_ON*]->(x:Version)
WHERE v.id = 'd_1_1'
RETURN DISTINCT x.id
```

The result is:

```
╒═══════╕
│"x.id" │
╞═══════╡
│"c_1_1"│
├───────┤
│"b_1_1"│
├───────┤
│"b_1_3"│
├───────┤
│"b_1_2"│
└───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, and suggested modifications. This is an approach I originally considered as it would be much simpler. However, as I tried to indicate in the original question, because new members will be added over time if a new member is added and falls within the version_min and version_max range of an existing records, I would then need to go back and identify all affected records and update all of them, which doesn't feel like it would scale. Ideally I would want to say `a_1_1` depends on `b_1_2` and anything newer, of which many don't yet exist and will be added later

Comment: Connecting related nodes with relationships is the "graphy" solution. Solutions requiring a lot of processing not involving transiting relationships are not really taking advantage of the strengths of a graph DB. Yes, you will use a lot of relationships, but that is why you are using a graph DB. Now, if multiple components might need the same version ranges, then you could have each `Component` related to a `Range` node, which would in turn be related to `Version` nodes; this would reduce the number of relationships and still be "graphy".

Comment: I wasn't concerned with the number of relationships that exist, but the maintenance of old records. e.g. if a thousand members all depend on X_1 (min version 1, and no upper limit). When X becomes version 2, it would mean every one of those thousand old records which depend on X need to be identified and then add a new relationship to update that they also depend on X_2. I accept the direct `(version)-[depend]-(version)` is preferable for querying, it was only the long term maintenance I'm uncertain about.

Comment: Would it be common for multiple components to be able to stably share the same version `Range` nodes, as I suggested? (Maybe `Range` is not the best name, since such a node can connect to any versions.)

Comment: I think I understand this proposal `(version)-[depend]-(ver_range)` and then many a:version, b:version can all have a path the to same ver_range? If so I think we end up in the same problem as my proposed schema, as the ver_range node could depend on a multiple other ver ranges dependent on the versions within its own range.

Comment: See my updated answer. Hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, which clarified it a lot and has pointed me in the right direction. This approach is much more scalable and as you stated allowed walking down an infinite `d:DEPENS_ON*..` path. For my use case I wouldn't make a range depend on another range, but instead the path would go `version->range->version->range...`.  It does still mean when inserting a new version it needs to determine what ranges it may be a member of and add a path, but that is much more scalable than finding any version. Thanks for this suggestion I plan to implement a solution in the next couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I have missunderstood your question but I believe this may be possible with the APOC Expand Paths function: https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/graph-querying/expand-paths/

Example Cypher for your graph:

```
MATCH (a:member{name:'prod_a_comp_1_v_1'})
CALL apoc.path.expand(a, ">DEPENDS_ON|<VERSION_OF", null, 1, -1)
YIELD path
RETURN path, length(path) AS hops
ORDER BY hops;
```

Example Results:

[image: neo4j result screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, this is useful and a move in the right direction. However, it still doesn't include a filter on the conditional logic inside the hops. In your solution I need a filter on the hops for `D.version_min <= V.version AND D.version_max >= V.version`, where D is the DEPENDS_ON relation, and V the VERSION_OF relation (version is also a property on each member too).